# How can one prevent a program from being opened with Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, taskkill

I want to try to prevent a program from being run with Python. For example, `notepad.exe`. My idea is the following, but will this work?

```
import os

i = 0

while i < 1:

    os.system('taskkill /f /im notepad.exe')
```

Comment: You may need elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work, but it will spawn a lot of console windows one after another. To avoid it you can try this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> from time import sleep
>>> si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
>>> si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
>>> while True:
        subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe', startupinfo=si)
        sleep(1) # delay 1 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this code.

Comment: How can I get elevated privileges? (without 3rd party modules)